# How to get color from the pixel? OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I would like to get color from the pixel in my game and save this color in variable. How to do it in opengl?

Answer (score 10):

[`glReadPixels()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml):

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-10, 10, -10, 10, -1, 1);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glPushMatrix();
        glScalef(5,5,5);
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glColor3ub(255,0,0);
            glVertex2f(-1,-1);
            glColor3ub(0,255,0);
            glVertex2f(1,-1);
            glColor3ub(0,0,255);
            glVertex2f(1,1);
        glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glutSwapBuffers();
}

void motion(int x, int y)
{
    y = glutGet( GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT ) - y;

    unsigned char pixel[4];
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
    cout << "R: " << (int)pixel[0] << endl;
    cout << "G: " << (int)pixel[1] << endl;
    cout << "B: " << (int)pixel[2] << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutCreateWindow("glReadPixels()");

    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(motion);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Beautiful code, short and works as expected. You have placed code for checking/displaying color of pixel inside display procedure. It works fast, but when the drawing is more complicated then program is not working properly. What about puting above code inside motion procedure, like [here] ?(http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Computer_graphic_techniques/2D/gfile#Viewer_for_programmers)

Answer (score 7):

```
struct{ GLubyte red, green, blue; } pixel;
glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, &pixel);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <math.h>
#include <gl/glut.h>

struct Point {
    GLint x;
    GLint y;
};

struct Color {
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
};

void init() {
    glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glPointSize(1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, 640, 0, 480);
}
  //this function is used for getting color of pixel
Color getPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y) {
    Color color;
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &color);
    return color;
}

void setPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y, Color color) {
    glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

void floodFill(GLint x, GLint y, Color oldColor, Color newColor) {
    Color color;
    color = getPixelColor(x, y);

    if(color.r == oldColor.r && color.g == oldColor.g && color.b == oldColor.b)
    {
        setPixelColor(x, y, newColor);
        floodFill(x+1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y+1, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x-1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y-1, oldColor, newColor);
    }
    return;
}

void onMouseClick(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    Color newColor = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f};
    Color oldColor = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};

    floodFill(320, 240, oldColor, newColor);
}

void draw_circle(Point pC, GLfloat radius) {
    GLfloat step = 1/radius;
    GLfloat x, y;

    for(GLfloat theta = 0; theta <= 360; theta += step) {
        x = pC.x + (radius * cos(theta));
        y = pC.y + (radius * sin(theta));
        glVertex2i(x, y);
    }
}

void display(void) {
    Point pt = {320, 240};
    GLfloat radius = 50;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        draw_circle(pt, radius);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE|GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480);
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200);
    glutCreateWindow("Open GL");
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(onMouseClick);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```