# Flood-fill fails to fill whole shape when reaching boundary color?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut, flood-fill, opengl-compat

I would like to draw some shape and then fill those shape with chosen color. At this time, I have just completed in drawing some basic shapes, but I'm still stuck at coloring them with flood-fill algorithm.

In details, I can not coloring the whole shape after clicking on it. All it could do is just drawing a line to the edge of the screen, leaking the chosen color outside the edge of the shape (ignoring the boundary color of the shape).

[image]

Here is all my work, can anyone help me???

```
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static int window;
static int value = 0;
GLsizei width, height;
int flag = 0;
bool up = false, down = false;

struct Point {
    GLint x;
    GLint y;
};
struct RGBColor
{
    GLfloat r;
    GLfloat g;
    GLfloat b;
};
struct Position
{
    Position() : x(0), y(0) {}
    float x;
    float y;
};
Position start;
Position finish; 
void init()
{
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    glPointSize(2.0);
    glLineWidth(2.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 500.0, 0.0);
}
void menu(int num) {
    if (num == 0) {
        glutDestroyWindow(window);
        exit(0);
    }
    else {
        value = num;
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void createMenu(void) 
{
    int sub_Triangle = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Isoceles right", 2);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Equilateral", 3);
    int menu_Triangle = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_Quadrilateral = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Rectangle", 4);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Square", 5);
    int menu__Quadrilateral = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_Oval = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Circle", 6);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Ellipse", 7);
    int menu_Oval = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_RegularPolygon = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Pentagon", 8);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Hexagon", 9);
    int menu_RegularPolygon = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_OtherShape = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Arrow", 10);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Star", 11);
    int menu_OtherShape = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_Operation = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Add", 12);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Subtract", 13);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Multiply", 14);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Divide", 15);
    int menu_Operation = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    int sub_ColorFill = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Red", 16);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Green", 17);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Blue", 18);
    int menu_ColorFill = glutCreateMenu(menu);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Line", 1);
    glutAddSubMenu("Triangle", sub_Triangle);
    glutAddSubMenu("Quadrilateral", sub_Quadrilateral);
    glutAddSubMenu("Oval", sub_Oval);
    glutAddSubMenu("Regular Polygon", sub_RegularPolygon);
    glutAddSubMenu("Other Shape", sub_OtherShape);
    glutAddSubMenu("Operation", sub_Operation);
    glutAddSubMenu("Color Fill", sub_ColorFill);
    glutAddMenuEntry("Shape Choice", 19);
    glutAttachMenu(GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON);
}
void draw_Line()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, finish.y);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void draw_IsocelesRight()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    int a = finish.y - start.y;
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y + a);
    glVertex2f(start.x + a, start.y + a);
}
void draw_Equilateral()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    int midx = (finish.x + start.x) / 2;
    int midbotx = (start.y - finish.y)*(1 / sqrt(3));
    int midboty = finish.y;
    glVertex2f(midx, start.y);
    glVertex2f(midx - midbotx, finish.y);
    glVertex2f(midx + midbotx, finish.y);
}
void draw_Rectangle()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, finish.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, finish.y);
}
void draw_Square()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);

    int a = finish.y - start.y;
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y + a);
    glVertex2f(start.x + a, start.y + a);
    glVertex2f(start.x + a, start.y);
}
void draw_Circle() 
{
    float PI = 3.14;
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    int size = sqrt(pow(finish.x - start.x, 2) + pow(finish.y - start.y, 2));
    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        float theta = (2 * 3.14 * i) / 360;
        glVertex2f((size / 2) * cos(theta) + finish.x, (size / 2) * sin(theta) + finish.y);
    }
}
void draw_Ellipse()
{
    float PI = 3.14;
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    int size1 = sqrt(pow(finish.x - start.x, 2) + pow(finish.x - start.x, 2));
    int size2 = sqrt(pow(finish.y - start.y, 2) + pow(finish.y - start.y, 2));

    for (int i = 0; i <= 360; i++)
    {
        float theta = (2 * 3.14 * i) / 360;
        glVertex2f((size1 / 2) * cos(theta) + finish.x, (size2 / 2) * sin(theta) + finish.y);
    }
}
void draw_Pentagon()
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double r = sqrt(pow(finish.x - start.x, 2));
    int sides = 5;
    int center_x = start.x + (finish.x - start.x) / 2;
    int center_y = start.y + (finish.y - start.y) / 2;

    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        double angle = i * 2 * PI / sides;
        glVertex2d(center_x + r*cos(angle), center_y + r*sin(angle));
    }
}
void draw_Hexagon()
{
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double r = sqrt(pow(finish.x - start.x, 2));
    int sides = 6;
    int center_x = start.x + (finish.x - start.x) / 2;
    int center_y = start.y + (finish.y - start.y) / 2;
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {
        double angle = i * 2 * PI / sides;
        glVertex2d(center_x + r*cos(angle), center_y + r*sin(angle));
    }
}
void draw_Arrow()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    const double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    double length = finish.x - start.x;
    double e = length / 3;
    double x1 = finish.x - e *  (1/tan(45 * PI /180));
    double y1 = start.y - e * tan(45 * PI / 180);
    double x2 = finish.x - e *  (1 / tan(45 * PI / 180));
    double y2 = start.y + e * tan(45 * PI / 180);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(x1, y1);
    glVertex2f(finish.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(x2, y2);
}
void draw_Star()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
    glVertex2f(100, 225);
    glVertex2f(210, 225);
    glVertex2f(250, 100);
    glVertex2f(290, 225);
    glVertex2f(400, 225);
    glVertex2f(315, 290);
    glVertex2f(350, 400);
    glVertex2f(250, 330);
    glVertex2f(150, 400);
    glVertex2f(185, 290);
}
void draw_Add()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    double length = finish.x - start.x;
    double half_length = length / 2;
    glVertex2f(start.x + half_length, start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x + half_length, start.y + length);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y + half_length);
    glVertex2f(start.x + length, start.y + half_length);
}
void draw_Subtract()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    double length = finish.x - start.x;
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x + length, start.y);
}
void draw_Multiply()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    double length = finish.x - start.x;
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x + length, start.y + length);
    glVertex2f(start.x + length , start.y);
    glVertex2f(start.x, start.y + length);
}


RGBColor getPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y)
{
    RGBColor color;
    glReadPixels(x, y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &color);
    return color;
}
void setPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y, RGBColor color)
{
    glColor3f(color.r, color.g, color.b);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x, y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
void floodFill(GLint x, GLint y, RGBColor oldColor, RGBColor newColor)
{
    RGBColor color;
    color = getPixelColor(x, y);
    if (color.r == oldColor.r && color.g == oldColor.g && color.b == oldColor.b)
    {
        setPixelColor(x, y, newColor);
        floodFill(x + 1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y + 1, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x - 1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y - 1, oldColor, newColor);
    }
    return;
}

bool IsSameColor(RGBColor x, RGBColor y) {
    if (x.r == y.r && x.b == y.b && x.g == y.g) {
        cout << "is same color true" << endl;
        return true;
    }
    else {
        cout << "is same color false" << endl;
        return false;
    }
}
void BoundaryFill(int x, int y, RGBColor F_Color, RGBColor B_Color) {
    cout << "bound fill" << endl;
    RGBColor currentColor;

    currentColor = getPixelColor(x, y);

    if (!IsSameColor(currentColor, B_Color) && !IsSameColor(currentColor, F_Color)) {
        cout << "bound" << endl;
        setPixelColor(x, y, F_Color);
        BoundaryFill(x - 1, y, F_Color, B_Color);
        BoundaryFill(x, y + 1, F_Color, B_Color);
        BoundaryFill(x + 1, y, F_Color, B_Color);
        BoundaryFill(x, y - 1, F_Color, B_Color);
    }
}

void display()
{
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        if (value == 1) {
            draw_Line();
        }
        else if (value == 2) {
            draw_IsocelesRight();
        }
        else if (value == 3) {
            draw_Equilateral();
        }
        else if (value == 4) {
            draw_Rectangle();
        }
        else if (value == 5) {
            draw_Square();
        }
        else if (value == 6) {
            draw_Circle();
        }
        else if (value == 7) {
            draw_Ellipse();
        }
        else if (value == 8) {
            draw_Pentagon();
        }
        else if (value == 9) {
            draw_Hexagon();
        }
        else if (value == 10) {
            draw_Arrow();
        }
        else if (value == 11) {
            draw_Star();
        }
        else if (value == 12) {
            draw_Add();
        }
        else if (value == 13) {
            draw_Subtract();
        }
        else if (value == 14) {
            draw_Multiply();
        }
        else if (value == 16) 
        {
            RGBColor newColor = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // red
            RGBColor oldColor = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f }; // black
            floodFill(start.x, start.y, oldColor, newColor);
        }
        glEnd();
        glutSwapBuffers();
        glFlush();
    }
    flag = 0;
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h); 
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0, w, h, 0);

    width = w;
    height = h;

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_DOWN)
    {
        down = true;
        start.x = x; //x1
        start.y = y; //y1
    }
    if (button == GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON && state == GLUT_UP)
    {
        if (down == true) {
            up = true;
            flag = 1;
            finish.x = x;
            finish.y = y;
        }

        down = false;
        up = false; 
    }
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(450, 100);
    window = glutCreateWindow("Coloring Shapes");

    init();
    createMenu();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you do this for practice, I suggest drawing filled shapes with `GL_TRIANGLES` or something similar. The way you currently do it will always be *slow*.

Answer (score 2):

The major issue is, that the coordinates which you pass to [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) are wrong.

When a point is drawn, by [`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertex.xml) then the coordinates are transformed by the modelview  and projection matrix.
So the orthographic projection is applied

> ```
> gluOrtho2D(0.0, 500.0, 500.0, 0.0);
> ```

But [`glReadPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glReadPixels.xml) directly read the fragment of the framebuffer. The coordinates are the x and y coordinate of the fragment in the framebuffer, where the bottom left is always (0, 0) and the top right is (*widht*, *height*).
You've to flip the y coordinate when you read the the fragment:

```cpp
RGBColor getPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y) 
{
    RGBColor color;
    glReadPixels(x, height-y, 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &color);
    return color;
}
```

---

In order not to sit rounding errors when calling `glVertex2i`, I recommend to use [`glRasterPos2i`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRasterPos.xml) and [`glDrawPixels`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml) instead. The coordinates to `glRasterPos2i` are transformed by the current modelview and projection matrix:

```cpp
void setPixelColor(GLint x, GLint y, RGBColor color)
{
    glRasterPos2i( x, y );
    glDrawPixels( 1, 1, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, &color );
    glFlush();
}
```

---

Since the color values are floating point values, you've to consider in inaccuracy when reading the color back from the GPU. Consider this when you compare the colors:

e.g.

<s>`color1.r == color2.r`</s>
`fabs(color1.r - color2.r)  < 0.001f`

Write a function which compares colors and use it in `floodFill`:

```cpp
bool isEqual( const RGBColor &c1, const RGBColor &c2 )
{
    return fabs(c1.r - c2.r) < 0.001f && fabs(c1.g - c2.g) < 0.001f && fabs(c1.b - c2.b) < 0.001f;
}

void floodFill(GLint x, GLint y, RGBColor oldColor, RGBColor newColor)
{
    RGBColor color;
    color = getPixelColor(x, y);
    if ( isEqual(color, oldColor) )
    {
        setPixelColor(x, y, newColor);
        floodFill(x + 1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y + 1, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x - 1, y, oldColor, newColor);
        floodFill(x, y - 1, oldColor, newColor);
    }
    return;
}
```

---

Anyway your code will only work for small areas, because the algorithm is recursive. The stack usage increased rapidly and causes a stack overflow immediately.
But it works for tine areas.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `glReadBuffer()` points to the right buffer. For double buffered rendering, `glDrawBuffer` and `glReadBuffer` point to `GL_BACK` per default.

Also there are some issues in your code. It seems to me you use double buffered rendering in an incorrect way. Single frame rendering procedure usually looks like this:

```
void display(){
    // user sees front buffer at the moment
    ClearScreen(); // glClear() or something, done on back buffer
    RenderAllYouHaveOnTheScene(); // rendered to back buffer
    SwapBuffers(); // glutSwapBuffers() does this in glut
    // Now back buffer becomes front buffer and user sees rendered scene.
    // Contents of current back buffer (which was front buffer
    // before glutSwapBuffers()) is undefined and you should 
    // clear it and redraw everything on next iteration.
}
```

And I don't see any point in swaping buffers in your `draw_Line()` procedure.

It is not a good thing to do float comparison with == operator. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/what-is-the-most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison). Use `unsigned char` pixel format or do float comparison with precision as described in the link.

Also check if your (x, y) coordinates do not overflow your screen boundaries (0 <= x < Width, 0 <= y < Height).

**Edit:** Also, as I noticed later, you specify `GLUT_SINGLE` in `glutInitDisplayMode` which means single buffered rendering, but use `glutSwapBuffers`, which should only be used in case of double buffered rendering. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28298540/difference-between-single-bufferedglut-single-and-double-buffered-drawingglut) to learn the difference.

Comment: All I do referenced to this site: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000921/how-to-get-color-from-the-pixel-opengl, they also made a comparison between float, so did I. I have tried to run their code, and it works well. I don't think float comparison is thing making the error here.

Comment: @magicww The code there does double buffered rendering in the way I described, but you don't. Especially note the `draw_Line()` remark in the answer. Also it uses ints as pixel format instead of float and does not do comparison on that.

Comment: Also you can just use single buffer approach.

Comment: Note that you have to draw bounding area for floodFill first before flooding it. In double buffered rendering you should do that each frame or save all pixels and redraw them each frame too, as swapping buffers does not guarantee to save the buffer contents and anyway it is outdated even if the contents is preserved.

Comment: @magicww if you are talking about the last answer in the list, than I think it has issues too. Answering to "they also made a comparison between float, so did I". Answers on the site are not guaranteed to be right or don't have mistakes.

Comment: Still it is a serious issue, even if float comparison may be not the reason for you problem to appear. And I said about many more issues in the answer.